# Is there a way to have iOS remember passwords to HTTP authenticated sites?

Tags: ios, password, mobile-safari, authentication

There's a page I frequently access on my iPhone that's protected by HTTP authentication, and I'm finding it annoying having to type in my username and password every time I want to access it. I tried saving the logged-in page as a home screen icon, but I'm still prompted every time. There isn't option to save my password when I'm logging in, and I can't find one in the settings either.

Is this possible?

[image]

<sup>example authentication screen to show what I'm referring to</sup>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that Safari on iOS doesn't support this natively. You have a couple options:

#### Workaround:

If you're not too worried about security, you can embed the username and password in the link itself, and bookmark that:

```
http://username:password@hostname.com/...
```

(Also of note: [it sounds like](http://lightyearsoftware.com/2010/05/remember-http-password-in-mobile-safari/) iOS may pop up a warning when you visit a link that includes a username and password.)

#### Alternative:

There is another browser called **[Atomic Web Browser](http://atomicwebbrowser.com/)** [[App Store link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-full-screen/id347929410?mt=8)] that can autofill HTTP authentication, among many other neat features.

Comment: Adding the username and password in the URL in a bookmark is clever - I can't find a way to do it on the device, but  I'll try creating it on my Mac and syncing it over. Thanks!

Comment: It's easy to do on the device. Bookmark the page you want to autofill authentication for and then go to edit the bookmark by holding down on it and choosing edit. In this windows you are able to edit the url to add the username and password like above.

Answer (score 3):

I just had to do this on the latest version of iOS as of this date, 10.1.1. I also had to make a shortcut on the home screen. Problem was, putting the username:password in the URL wouldn't work because Safari would immediately remove the username:password from the URL, so I couldn't capture the fully-formed URL in a home screen shortcut.

I made a web page that redirected (JavaScript) to the fully-formed target URL (e.g., http://user:pass@hostname). I navigated to it in Safari, and Safari preserved the fully-formed URL for some reason. From there I made a home screen shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the app 1Password. You just have to use the browser inside of the app.

Create a login in the app with the appropriate URL, username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Mercury browser will also save Basic Authentication on iOS and is a free download.

http://mercury-browser.com

Be sure to finish typing and then press "Save" before logging in. You may have to do it a couple times for different parts of the site.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't managed to make Mobile Safari prefill the dialogue, you can manually add the credentials via the Accounts & Passwords section in Settings. There's an 'Add password' button at the bottom of the list (search for something to make it shorter).

Then, next time you get presented with the dialogue you can tap the key icon in the autocomplete bar and search for the credential and have it fill in the dialogue fields for you. Not perfect, but better than nothing.

N.B. I did also try moving the creds from my `login` keychain on my Mac to the `iCloud` one, so that it would sync across, but it wouldn't show up on my iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 15, Settings > Passwords allows adding new entries by hand. You can fill in the website URL and the credentials here. The next time the basic auth dialog shows up, it will not, unfortunately, be pre-filled, but you will be presented with the Passwords button in your on-screen keyboards once you focus either of the username / password fields and from there you can pick the credentials. It's not completely straight-forward, but it is the best option I found, especially because some websites do not support reading the username and password from the URL, only from the HTTP header, so the trick with the bookmark with the credentials in it doesn't work everywhere.